# Terraform Import using Terraform modules in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a Terraform template file which uses some externally sourced modules (Stored in a Git repo) and I am trying to import my ECS cluster and I have tried to run

`terraform import module.module_name arn::here`

But I get an error regarding resource addressing and that the resource address must contain a full resource spec.

Comment: Can you please post the error message with your question?

Answer (score 8):

Run a `terraform plan` first, and you will see all of the resources that your module will be attempting to create.

Find the ECS cluster referenced in there - it will likely show up as Terraform trying to create a new resource (Because that's what it should do :-))

Now **that** is the name of the Terraform resource you want to address, it'll be much longer than just `module.module_name` it'll be something like `module.module_name.ecs_cluster.your_ecs_cluster_resource_name` or something.

And then rather than using the ARN as the second argument, you just want to use the cluster name as the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_cluster.html#import) states.

Comment: In the example above, it would be `module.my_example_pipeline.azuredevops_build_definition.pipeline`.

Answer (score 3):

You're only able to import the resources within the module - the module itself has no corresponding ARN in AWS.